# Test trained ML model with new data - how to deal with one_hot_encoding?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I trained a DNN model on the following dataset:

```
hash       name  surname  datetime             total  nb_success  result 
axBBdnn78  aaa   bbb      2016-01-01 00:01:26  50.00   1           OK
```

My goal was to predict the value of the `result` column.

I one_hot encoded all the strings value, which gives me a lot of features and then train and save my model.

I now want to test it on a new dataset (only one entry). I begin by loading the row into a DataFrame:

```
food = np.array(['xxxsBF44', 'feature_name', 'feature_surname', 'feature_datetime', 'feature_total', 'feature_nb_success', 'feature_result'])
food = np.reshape(food, (1, 7))
data = pd.DataFrame(food, columns=names)
data['amount'] = data['amount'].astype(float)
```

Now, of course I need to prepare this data, as I did while training my DNN. But it does not make sense to one_hot encode the string features, since it only consists of one row. 
The result of the one_encoding would be something like:

```
hash       name  surname  datetime  total  nb_success  result 
0          0     1.0      1.0       50.00  1           1
```

So the prediction will be made with non-sense data.

My question is then how can I make a prediction with my saved model, and how to handle the non-sense one_hot encoding on only one row ?